# Adding custom jar to ant's classpath before running a target

Tags: ant, classpath

I am trying to add more custom jar to ant's classpath before it actually calls a target, but it is not taking my custom jar & hence I get error from ant's taskdef class ClassName cannot be found. Is there a way to handle this?.

```
main.ksh

#/bin/ksh

.
.

ANT_CLASSPATH=$JDK_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar
ANT_CLASSPATH=$ANT_CLASSPATH:$ANTBUILD_HOME/lib/ant-$ANT_VERSION.jar
.
.

echo $ANT_CLASSPATH
export ANT_CLASSPATH

.
.
# java call with framed ANT_CLASSPATH to ant target which is part of main build.xml ### This call, I don't want to run without my custom jar in ANT_CLASSPATH ###
```

My new ksh file looks like below, where I am adding new custom jar to ANT_CLASSPATH

```
sub.ksh

#/bin/ksh


# Adding some more to jars to ANT_CLASSPATH

export ANT_CLASSPATH=../lib/custom/custom-3.0.jar


main.ksh new-build.xml $*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As initial idea was not to touch main.ksh script, have not seen it closely. My bad it has to be corrected if it has to use exported value form sub.ksh.

I just has to append the exported value in first line:

ANT_CLASSPATH=$ANT_CLASSPATH:$JDK_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar

Answer (score 8):

The ANT classpath is best managed within the build file:

```
<path id="runtime.path">
  <pathelement location="lib/custom/custom-3.0.jar"/>
  ..
  ..
</path>

<path id="build.path">
  <pathelement location="lib/custom-anttask-3.0.jar"/>
  ..
  ..
</path>

<!-- Use the paths using 'classpathref' attributes on tasks -->
<java .... classpathref="runtime.path"/>
<taskdef .... classpathref="build.path"/>
```

Comment: I agree. But I found problem when running a target which is part of another xml file & file has taskdef to a class which was not added to ant's classpath.

Comment: @user1587504 You've missed the point. Don't manage the classpath using the environment variable. This is inflexible and inaccessible. Instead create paths inside the ANT build and use these for java and taskdef tasks. See update.